# Get Github "tag" created from a github commit

Tags: python, github, github-api

I wrote a python script to get the latest commit from "main" branch and the Tag created using that commit. As soon as we merge to main, a tag is automatically created and I want to fetch that using python. But unable to find that. Below is the script:

```
def get_latest_hash_id(repo_owner, repo_name, branch_name, auth_token):
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/commits/{branch_name}"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data['sha']
    return None

def get_tag_with_hash(repo_owner, repo_name, hash_id, auth_token):
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/refs/tags"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Token {auth_token}"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print("json data = " ,data)
        for tag in data:
            if tag['object']['sha'] == hash_id:
                return tag['ref']
repo_owner = "company"
repo_name = "app-api"
branch_name = "main"
auth_token = getpass.getpass("Enter your GitHub personal access token: ")
hash_id = get_latest_hash_id(repo_owner, repo_name, branch_name, auth_token)
if hash_id:
    tag = get_tag_with_hash(repo_owner, repo_name, hash_id, auth_token)
    if tag:
        print(f"The latest hash ID on branch {branch_name} is {hash_id}, and the tag created from that hash ID is: {tag}")
    else:
        print(f"No tag found with hash ID {hash_id}")
else:
    print(f"No hash ID found for branch {branch_name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
Instead of using

```
url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/refs/tags"
```

I have to use:

```
url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/tags?per_page=200"
```